# Self-difference of a list i(difference of sequential list values)

Tags: python

I have a list, a time series, `s`.  I would like to efficiently take the "self difference" of the list: `output[n] = s(n)-s(n+1)`.  What's an efficient (in terms of time) way of doing this?

My eventual goal is to have a list representing this below, with this question implementing the first step:

∑[∡s1​(t)−∡s1​(t−1)]⋅[∡s2​(t+τ)−∡s2​(t−1+τ)]

Comment: how do you want to deal with the ends?, i.e. what should happen at `s[len(s) - 1]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - this was unspecified in my reference - please see my edit for more context

Comment: ... well have considered iterating through the list and subtracting?

Comment: `[b - a for (a,b) in zip(x, x[1:])]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an efficient way, use numpy:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

```
import numpy as np
s = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 0])
output = np.diff(s)
print(output)    #  [ 1  2  3 -7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
output = [s[n] - s[n+1] for n in range(len(n)-1)]
```

Let the Python run-time system do any optimizations it wants; this method saves *your* time as programmer and maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a third-party tool, [`more_itertools.difference`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.difference).

```
import more_itertools as mit


list(mit.difference([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```